# How to move AsyncTask FROM Adapter onBindViewHolder() TO Activity onChildEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

I am using a RecyclerView to display Tweets, with some of the data stored in Firebase.  When the app starts, I use a ChildEventListener to populate the feed, which will help for efficiency later when new tweets are added and the feed has to be updated.  My problem is that some data needs to be retrieved with twitter4j API (i.e. the author of the Tweet's profile image) and can't be stored in Firebase.  I am currently getting this data with an AsyncTask in my adapter onBindViewHolder().  I am curious how I can instead move this to be done in my ChildEventListener so the data is available before the adapter is set.  When I run the AsyncTask in my adapter onBindViewHolder(), the profile image takes a bit to load which is obviously not desirable for user experience.

AsyncTask:

```
public class StatusAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Integer, Status>
{
  TweetListAdapterFeed tweetListAdapterFeed;
  TweetListAdapterFeed.ViewHolder viewHolder;
  int position;

  public StatusAsyncTask(TweetListAdapterFeed tweetListAdapterFeed, TweetListAdapterFeed.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
  {
    this.tweetListAdapterFeed = tweetListAdapterFeed;
    this.viewHolder = viewHolder;
    this.position = position;
  }

  protected twitter4j.Status doInBackground(Long... tweetStatusId)
  {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
    twitter4j.Status status;

    try
    {
      status = twitter.showStatus(tweetStatusId[0]);
      return status;
    }
    catch (TwitterException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(twitter4j.Status status)
  {
    if (status != null)
    {
      viewHolder.retweetCount.setText(String.valueOf(status.getRetweetCount()));
      viewHolder.likeCount.setText(String.valueOf(status.getFavoriteCount()));

      Picasso.get().load(status.getUser().get400x400ProfileImageURL()).fit().into(viewHolder.profileImage);
    }
  }
}
```

TweetListAdapterFeed onBindViewHolder():

```
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int i)
  {
    int viewType = holder.getItemViewType();
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder)holder;

    // Update Like and Retweet Count via AsyncTask
    new StatusAsyncTask(this, viewHolder, i).execute(mData.get(i).getTweetStatusID());

    ...
  }
```

ChildEventListener:

```
public static final List<TweetData> listFeedList = new ArrayList<>();
public static TweetListAdapterFeed mAdapter;

ChildEventListener tweetChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
  {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists())
    {
      TweetData tweetData = dataSnapshot.getValue(TweetData.class);
      if ((tweetData != null) && (!tweetData.tweetText.equals("")))
      {
        listFeedList.add(listFeedList.size(), tweetData);
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(listFeedList.size());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you want the photo to be ready at the same time as the new item is added. This can be done, but when you get a new data, you have to use the same class as your **StatusAsyncTask** and receive the photo and pass it completely to your adapter That is, download the photo and pass the address of the photo in storage to your adapter . This is the hard way

But the easier way to get a better view is to use a fixed placeholder image in XML for photos.

Another way is to [use Picasso's own placeholder](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-placeholders-errors-and-fading).